# Возможно ли убрать управление видео на сайте?

Tags: html, css

Что возможно добавить в мой код для того, чтобы при нажатии на "клик" - видео адаптировалось во весь сайт, но при этом не происходило того, что сайт необходимо скролить ?

Возможно ли убрать органы управления видео снизу и сделать сайт после нажатия на "клик" не кликабельным ?

```js
let bott = document.getElementById('myBott')
bottToggle = document.getElementById('myBt')
popupClose = document.querySelector('.close')

bottToggle.onclick = () => {
  bott.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: "Droid Sans";
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.Bt {
  flex: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 46%;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Bt:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  background: #009200;
}

.bott {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(102, 104, 104);
}

.bott-body {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.copiright {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.copiright div {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans" rel="stylesheet" />
<button id="myBt" class="Bt">КЛИК</button>
<div id="myBott" class="bott">
  <div class="bott-content">
    <div class="bott-body">
      <video controls autoplay loop>
        <source src="https://i.imgur.com/leENLvB.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="copiright">
  <div>
    Copyright 2021 All rights reserved. Designed by Ba-Ba-Duuk
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Что возможно добавить в мой код для того, чтобы при нажатии на "клик"
> видео адаптировалось во весь сайт, но при этом не происходило того, что сайт необходимо скролить?

С этим вопросом мы разобрались. Смотрите на результат. Кроме этого, исправил у вас ещё ряд допущенных вами ошибок в `CSS`.

> Возможно ли убрать органы управления видео снизу?

Управление то убрать можно (но еще зависит от того, какой плеер вы будете использовать). Но как при этом тогда пользователь будет включать/выключать видео? К тому же, поверьте мне, это совсем плохая идея, не стоит этого делать.

```js
let bott = document.getElementById('myBott')
bottToggle = document.getElementById('myBt')
popupClose = document.querySelector('.close')

bottToggle.onclick = () => {
  bott.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: "Droid Sans";
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.Bt {
  outline: none;
  flex: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #000000;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Bt:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  background: #009200;
}

.bott {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(102, 104, 104);
}

bott-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bott-body {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 0;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

.bott-body video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.copiright {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.copiright div {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans" rel="stylesheet" />
<button id="myBt" class="Bt">КЛИК</button>
<div id="myBott" class="bott">
  <div class="bott-content">
    <div class="bott-body">
      <video controls autoplay loop>
        <source src="https://i.imgur.com/leENLvB.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="copiright">
  <div>
    Copyright 2021 All rights reserved. Designed by Ba-Ba-Duuk
  </div>
</div>
```

> Возможно ли сделать сайт после нажатия на "клик" не кликабельным ?

И это можно сделать. Смотрите пример, как один из вариантов - просто "занавесить" его отдельным элементом. В этом случае вы убиваете двух зайцев - и страница становится недоступной для пользователя, и управление прячется, т.к. оно появляется при наведении на видео, что мы такой шторкой исключаем. Но эта идея даже больше, чем плохая. Поверьте, пользователь в этом случае достанет и вспомнит из своего словарного запаса все скверные и бранные слова и мысленно направит их вам. Не стоит этого делать.

```js
let blocking = document.querySelector('.blocking')
let bott = document.getElementById('myBott')
bottToggle = document.getElementById('myBt')
popupClose = document.querySelector('.close')

bottToggle.onclick = () => {
  bott.style.display = "block";
  blocking.style.height = "100vh";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: "Droid Sans";
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.Bt {
  outline: none;
  flex: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #000000;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Bt:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  background: #009200;
}

.bott {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(102, 104, 104);
}

bott-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bott-body {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 0;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

.bott-body video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.copiright {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.copiright div {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000000;
}

.blocking {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: height 5s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans" rel="stylesheet" />
<button id="myBt" class="Bt">КЛИК</button>
<div id="myBott" class="bott">
  <div class="bott-content">
    <div class="bott-body">
      <video controls autoplay loop>
        <source src="https://i.imgur.com/leENLvB.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="copiright">
  <div>
    Copyright 2021 All rights reserved. Designed by Ba-Ba-Duuk
  </div>
</div>
<div class="blocking"></div>
```